# ProLiant DL120 G7 manually increase fan speed

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, fan

Because of the applications wich are running on my ProLiant DL120 G7 it has usually high cpu loads. That is no problem, all running very well. But the CPU temp hits 75 degree celsius, and the fan's are just rotating at 50% speed. I would like to manually let the fan's run at full speed, to increase cooling.

In the BIOS I can choose between "optimal cooling" and afair "efficient cooling" or so... there is no manual fan control - at least I dont see it.

Does someone know how I could increase the servers fan speed?

Comment: Have you talked to the HP server technicians about that problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's no manual fan control. Trust your server and the engineering that went into the design of the product. This isn't a *Supermicro* server :)

The option that HP recommends for workloads that may require additional cooling or system configurations with certain PCIe hardware installed is to select the "Optimal" or "Increased" cooling option in the BIOS. Otherwise, leave it be. The system will ramp up if it needs to.

Also, be sure to upgrade the firmware of your ILO and system BIOS, as more options have appeared over time with successive firmware releases. The quickest way to handle your entire system is to boot with the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD image](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx).